# Can't use a setState call in the onchanged callback in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-state

I am trying to map a `TextFormField`s value to a state variable in flutter

```
class _PageState extends State<AddPage> {

  String _tag = ''; // this is the state variable

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
       ....
      return Scaffold(
          ....
          ....
          TextFormField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: "Tag *"),
                  onChanged: (val) {
                      print(val);
                      setState(() {
                        _tag = val; // here I am trying to update the state variable
                      });
                  },
                ), // TextFormField end

    )};
    }
}
```

as you can see I am listening to the `onChanged` event and trying to update the state variable `_tag`.

but the state does not update and the text field loses focus ( I think because the UI rerendors because of the `setState()` call). No character is displayed the form field as well. any idea what I am doing wrong? am I listening to the right event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep `_formKey` as a state variable.

```
class _PageState extends State<AddPage> {

  String _tag = ''; // this is the state variable
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       ....
      return Scaffold(
          ....
          ....
          TextFormField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: "Tag *"),
                  onChanged: (val) {
                      print(val);
                      setState(() {
                        _tag = val; // here I am trying to update the state variable
                      });
                  },
                ), // TextFormField end

    )};
    }
}
```

By keeping as a function variable, this creates the `Form` with new instance, so your state won't be persisted after `setState`.

Comment: nice find on the form key. I was thinking over it for some time

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextEditingController` to handle inputs of `TextFormField` instead of using `onChange`.